# journal files quite big, hidden content?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd-journald, journalctl

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a server. Currently my /var/log/journal folder grows rapidly (about 1Gb in a week) and I don't understand why.

If I check the logs with `journalctl` I cannot see any major problem, just a lot of SSH connections, which is fine.

I tried looking at a specific journal file with `journalctl --file` and it only showed like 14 log lines, but the file has 8MB, so there must be something hidden within this file. I also tried the `--all` flag, but that didn't change anything.

I'm not very familiar with the journal, can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

If scrolling through journalctl mostly shows `ssh` connections, then  that's probably is what is filling up your journal.

Here are a couple of things you can do:

1. Temporarily stop logging from that unit.

```
sudo systemctl edit sshd.service
```

In this fille add:

```
[System]
StandardOutput=null
```

You could also use `StandardOutput=file:path/to/file` if you want to save those logs for audit or review while you are doing your test.  Leave this for a week and see if your journal continues to grow and a crazy rate.  When you are done your test, `systemctl edit sshd.service` your changes away.

2. Set limits on the size of the journal.  If you are concerned about the journal dominating disk-space, you can set limits with [`journald.conf`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/journald.conf.5.html).  Something like this might help:

```
# /etc/systemd/journal.conf.d/maxsize.conf
[Journal]
SystemMaxUse=1G
```